# Survminer - arrange multiple ggsurvplot and ggadjustedcurves

Tags: r, survminer

I would like to combine survminer plots (like an `arrange_ggsurvplots()` ): ggsurvplot (for Kaplan Meier model) and ggadjustedcurves (for Cox).

```
library(survminer)
fitKM  <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
fitCox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p1 = ggsurvplot(fitKM, data = lung)
p2 = ggadjustedcurves(fitCox, data = lung,variable = "sex")
```

When I do :

```
arrange_ggsurvplots(x = list(p1,p2))
```

I have

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : An object of class ggsurvplot is required.
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ggsurvplot` object is a `list` where the plot of the survival curves is stored as an element named `plot` which is `ggplot` object, whereas `ggadjustedcurves` returns a `ggplot` object by default.

Hence, one option to combine both plots would be to use one of the available options for `ggplot` objects like e.g. `patchwork`:

```r
library(survminer)
library(survival)

fitKM  <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
fitCox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p1 = ggsurvplot(fitKM, data = lung)
p2 = ggadjustedcurves(fitCox, data = lung, variable = "sex")

library(patchwork)

p1$plot + p2
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your reply. Upvoted. Any way to add `Patients at-risk` table below the unadjusted plot or both plots?